# Checking for Battery status / USB plugged is not consistent

Tags: android, usb, batterylevel

I need to know if my Android device is charging and if it is connected to the usb, so I'm using the following code:

```
    IntentFilter intentFilter;
    Intent intent;
    intentFilter= new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    intent= mContext.registerReceiver(null, intentFilter);

    int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);   
    boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING || status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

    int chargePlug = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
    boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
    boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;
```

My problem is: sometimes, depending on the tested device, while device is obviously connected to USB (I can tell by having access to all data folders), it still returns usbCharge =false.
Can anyone think of a reason why? I should mention I'm always using the same device type, just different devices...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: "it still returns usbCharge =false" -- is `acCharge` `true` in those cases? Personally, I would not rely on the distinction between those cases, considering the device to be plugged into power in either of them.

Comment: acCharge is also false

Comment: OK, that I can't explain, sorry.

Comment: I found out that it only happens when I change the USB status while app is running. so the listener is not working (it gives the correct result if the usb was plugged/unplugged prior running the app). So why doesn't it recognize the change? could it be because I have few threads running in my app?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.e("test","reciver");
    final Intent mIntent = context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    int status = mIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
//        
//        boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
//                status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

    int chargePlug = mIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
    boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
    boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;
    Log.e("test",usbCharge+"");
    Toast.makeText(context,usbCharge+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//        Toast.makeText(context,acCharge+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```